# Import all of the source code to Bitbucket Git initially

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is there a way to import all of the code into Bitbucket Git repo that I have?

I would like to push all of the files in there initially from my local machine then start from there.

I find docs that states importing from Github and others but nothing about existing project that haven't used version control before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

- Create a new repo in bitbucket.
- `cd project-root`
- `git init`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
- `git remote add origin url-of-your-bitbucket-remote`
- `git push -u origin master`

Notice that most of these steps are mentioned when you create the BitBucket repo.

Comment: Official documentation on this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Import+code+from+an+existing+project#Importcodefromanexistingproject-Importanexisting%2Cunversionedcodeprojecttoanemptyrepository

Comment: If you are getting errors when pushing changes to bitbucket, you may try git push --mirror url-of-your-bitbucket-remote

Comment: Unfortunately these steps create a local repo as a byproduct which might not be desireable as it adds files to your local filesystem.